# how to count in django templates

Tags: python, django, templates, counter

Hi I am trying to count infringement inside templates. The results I am getting for 'a' the counter is 1 1 (two separate values) instead of total count of 2 or 1 1 1 instead of a total of 3. Please help as I am new to programming.

html

```
 {% for infringer in page_obj %}
  <tr>
  <td>{{infringer.id}}</td>
  <td>{{infringer.created|date:"d M, Y"}}</td>
  <td>{{infringer.name}}</td>
  <td>{{infringer.brand_name}}</td>
  <td>{{infringer.status}}</td>
  <td>
  {% with a=0 %}
  
  {% for i in inc %}
  {% if infringer.id == i.infringer.id %}
  
  {{ a|add:"1" }}
 
  
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   {% endwith %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login') 
def infringerlist(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q') != None else '' 
    ings= Infringer.objects.filter(Q(created__icontains=q) | Q(id__icontains=q) | Q(status__name__icontains=q) | Q(brand_name__icontains=q) | Q(name__icontains=q), customer=request.user.customer,)
    paginator = Paginator(ings, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    inc = Infringement.objects.filter(customer=request.user.customer)
    context= {'page_obj': page_obj, 'inc': inc}
    return render(request,'base/infringers_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Use the inbuilt `counter0` filter to access  the current iteration of the loop
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for
`{% if infrigner.id == page_obj[forloop.counter0].id %}`

Comment: forloop doesnt work because their is an if condition.

Comment: OK, you an consider moving the counting logic to the view, passing it in the context and using templates for displaying it?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. The for loop to display the table data is on the template.  I am just trying to get a count of infringements for each row of infringers. Code above

Comment: similar questions that could be helpful for your case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714290/django-count-specific-items-of-a-many-to-one-relationship